# Filename containing Arabic and western characters

Tags: java, csv, export-to-csv, arabic, right-to-left

I'm exporting a file as CSV. It's name is language-dependent. For this reason, I'm combining the name including the extension as follows:

`String file = fileName+"."+fileExtension;`

In Arabic, the variable fileName contains "تصدير" and in English it contains "export". The variable fileExtension always contains "csv".

Now, the problem is that the full string in Arabic looks like "csv.تصدير". Incorrect in my opinion.
In English it's "export.csv", I.e. correct.

Is there a solution for this issue or is "csv.تصدير" correct for an Arabic system setup?

Comment: I think you are missing a directional marker. Windows displays the file natively as  `654321.txt` where 1..6 is each Arab glyph in order of appearance. Try to put the text as you want it `تصدير.txt`  in a text file and analyze it at byte level.  Alternatively, it could be what prints to the screen that interprets unicode wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try the following tool to get more clarity:  https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/bidi.jsp